# Real Analysis: Prove the following statements true or provide a counterexample if they are false

Tags: real-analysis

c) If $ f $ is differentiable on $ (a,b) $ and $ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a+}f(x) $ exists and is finite, then for each $ x \in (a,b) $ there is a $ c  $ between $ a $ and $ x $ such that $ f(x) - f(a+) = f'(c)(x-a). $

d) If $ f $ and $ g  $ are differentiable on $ [a,b] $ and $ |f'(x)| \leq 1 \leq |g'(x)| $ for all $ x \in (a,b), $ then $ |f(x) - f(a)| \leq |g(x) - g(a)| $ for all $ x \in [a,b] $.

Could someone provide hints on how to begin both proofs? I apologize if these are trivial. I am having a difficult time making the connection between the derivative of a function, cord functions, and the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: what means $f(a+)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c) If we define $f(a):=f(a+)$, then f is continuous on $[a,b)$. The assertion follows from the mean value theorem.

d) Use the generalized mean value theorem.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you give me a reference on partially extending intervals from open to closed? I never covered this in class.

Answer (score 0):

consider $y=x$, from $(0,1)$ and $y = 5-x$ from$(\infty,0]$ as counterexample for first case. A hint for the second problem: $g(x)$ is monotonic and use the bounds of derivative.